# Найти максимум. Не выводится решение ответа

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код который должен после ведение с клавиатуры чисел должен находить максимум, но почему-то этого не происходит и я не могу понять в чем причина.

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>решение 7</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Calculate(FormObj){
var a = FormObj.a.value*1;
var b = FormObj.b.value*1;
var U = FormObj.U.value*1;
return U = Math.max(Math.max(a,b), Math.pow(b,2),Math.pow(a,2));
console.log(U);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2></h2>
<form name="cal">
<table>
<tr>
<td>a:</td>
<td><input type="text" size=30 name="a"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>b:</td>
<td><input type="text" size=30 name="b"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>U:</td>
<td><input size=30 name="U"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" Value="Посчитать"
onClick="Calculate(this.form)">
</form>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: А зачем там pow?

Comment: Убрать return перед U.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>решение 7</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function Calculate(FormObj){
         var a = +FormObj.a.value;
         var b = +FormObj.b.value;
         var U = +FormObj.U.value;
         var max = Math.max(a, b, Math.pow(b,2), Math.pow(a,2));
         console.log(max);
         return max;
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2></h2>
      <form name="cal">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>a:</td>
               <td><input type="text" size=30 name="a"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>b:</td>
               <td><input type="text" size=30 name="b"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>U:</td>
               <td><input size=30 name="U"></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <input type="button" Value="Посчитать"
            onClick="Calculate(this.form)">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```